# MATLAB: Changing color for my heat maps

Tags: matlab, colors, heatmap

The sample script below is for creating four heat maps with the same color scale limit. I set it this way in order for me to differentiate the differences between each heat map; however, the difference is barely noticeable. The color is currently set in a general blue range (light to darker blue). What can I do to change it to maybe a hot/cold color scheme?

```
cd C:\Users\Aiskya\Desktop\Subjects\total
A = dlmread('avg_data.txt')

cd C:\Users\Aiskya\Desktop\Subjects\total
B = dlmread('avg_data.txt')

cd C:\Users\Aiskya\Desktop\Subjects\total
C = dlmread('avg_data.txt')

cd C:\Users\Aiskya\Desktop\Subjects\total
D = dlmread('avg_data.txt')

minValue = min([A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)]);
maxValue = max([A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)]);
HA.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HB.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HC.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HD.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];

xvalues =  
{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'};
yvalues = 
{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'};

subplot(2,2,1)
HA = heatmap(xvalues,yvalues,A);
HA.Title = 'A';
HA.XLabel = 'regions';
HA.YLabel = 'regions';
HA.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
```

There are a total of 4 subplots, which all look like the lines above. All the heatmaps are shown in "MATLAB heatmap reference" has a similar color setting, and I couldn't find a specific property that talks about this. I appreciate the help!

*Colorbar doesn't seem to do the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color map used using the `Colormap` property of the `HeatmapChart` object:

```
HA.Colormap = parula(64);
```

(parula is the default color map for figures) or

```
HA.Colormap = hot(64);
```

To get a list of all default color maps in MATLAB, type

```
help graph3d
```

(scroll to where it says "Color maps").

Note that when you type `HA` at the command prompt, you get to see a few of the properties of the `HeatmapChart` object, but not all. At the bottom of the list is a link that says "Show all properties". There you can find everything that you can tweak about these heat maps. More information is also available [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.heatmapchart-properties.html).

Comment: Indeed, it's the number of colors in the color map. I looked at the default blue colormap of the heat map, and it had 64 colors. I thought I'd replicate that. Feel free to try it with more colors, see what happens! :)