# Matlab 2017b heatmap, make zero values white

Tags: matlab

In Matlab 2017b, the default [heapmap](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html) color ranges from light blue to dark blue. How can I make zero values white instead of light blue (it is difficult to distinguish between low numbers and zero in the current form).

```
cdata = [0 0.005 1; 1 0 0.0006; 0.4 0.20 0.1];
h = heatmap(cdata);
```

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801345/7328782 . You can create a color map, then modify it by setting `cmap(end,:)=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color map zero values to white by changing the colormap values by 
  map=colormap(heatmap(cdata));
  map(1,:)=1;

And when plotting the figure map use the defined color map as follows
  h = heatmap(cdata,'Colormap',map);